# Using `set_transient()` when saving a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions, transient

I've got multiple custom post types registered via a plugin and one of them is used as a precursor for multiple other queries.  In an attempt to reduce queries throughout the site, I've attempted to include the one CPT, we'll call it `post_type_x` and some of it's `post_meta` data in a 'transient record'.

Everything is working exactly as I want it to - the data I'm placeing in a transient record is available for me when I need it, whenever I need it, etc and I've managed to reduce an entire query for some of the more complex pages on the site.

However, I'm wondering about a very 'edge' case:

When I am creating a new `post_type_x` post the transient record is already set and if the new `post_type_x` fits the requirements of the original check that determines which `post_type_x` posts to add via `set_transient()` it won't get added for users currently browsing. I'll probably set the transients to expire and reset after 12 or 24 hours.

This in itself isn't actually a problem as any newly added `post_type_x` won't need to be included for a typical user of the site as soon it's created.  These CPT posts will usually be created weeks or even months before standard users needed to access them and by that time they'll have visited the site multiple times and the transient record will have been repeatedly updated. Basically by the time a typical user needs it, it'll be available to them.

However, the one segment of people that *may* need to see new `post_type_x` posts loaded into the transient record as soon as it has been created would be administrators, because they're setting up programs and have a lot of related details across other CPTs and custom tables to work through.  The data in the transient record would, ideally, be updated as soon as new CPT post is created or an existing one is updated.

So, what I'm wondering... ...is there a reliable hook/action within WP I can use that runs immediately AFTER the `add_action( 'save_post_post_type_x', 'post_type_x_save_function', 1, 2 );`

That way I can be sure that the admin user is getting a the transient record set as soon as they've implemented a change to one of the `post_type_x` posts.

**I've modified my question above to use transient records instead of wp_cache. After doing some additional codex reading and taking Tom J Nowell's comments into consideration, I believe that setting a transient record is the best option.**

Comment: WP already stores posts and their meta in WP_Cache to avoid duplicate queries. WP also fetches all of a posts meta and terms pre-emptively all at once to avoid follow up queries later ( this is all assuming you are not using `get_posts` with the suppress filters option still turned on ). WP_Cache also doesn't last beyond the same request unless you have an object cache or a plugin that provides persistence. There's no need to store posts and their meta in the WP Cache yourself

Comment: I'm using post meta from the custom CPT on pages where that post isn't called via a Query to build SQL queries on custom tables.  So what I'm trying to avoid is running a check on all of the CPT's posts looking for parameters that match value Y, to determine which post_meta to then in turn use to build my custom SQL queries. I also went the taxonomy route when I was mapping things out, but that was still another query to run before I could build my SQL queries. An alternative is also adding the data I need to wp_options, but from what I was reading wp_cache was faster.

Comment: if you have a persistent object cache then the meta is already there from the last time, you don't need to manually add it yourself. If wp_cache is not persistent then none of this matters because when the page is served it all vanishes and the slate is wiped clean. As for the hook you're asking about, WP already handles this, you don't need to add your own. You're duplicating work WP is already doing. Otherwise, why not use the hook itself and put your filter last?

Comment: Also, you can't rely on wp cache always being there, it may be cleared for many reasons, it's ephemeral. Maybe the server rebooted, or the cache was cleared, or like most servers it isn't persistent and is blank at the start of every page request. Object caches have limits, and things expire. At some point it still has to run the query to get the data to cache and you want it to be a fast query not a slow query. If you're trying to avoid a slow query, a transient of the queries result would be better than putting the precursors of the SQL query in wp_cache

Comment: I wasn't trying to add a hook or action of my own, just discern which of the existing ones would be the best place to reset the `wp_cache()`.  I'm now re-considering a transient, but then the question still remains, which action or hook would be best to target so that the transient record is updated whenever a CPT post is updated or added, so that for administrative users, the transient is always up to date.  I'll edit my question to include the transient option.

Comment: What I meant was that you don't need to discover a new hook that happens after the one you specified, just use the very same hook you specified and set the priority so your function runs last.